# JetBrains DataGrip search utility

Tags: datagrip, sql-search

Is it possible to search a specific string (e.g. table name) in JetBrains DataGrip?

I'm looking for something like [Red Gate's SQL Search](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-search/)

Answer (score 2):

Navigate to any database object with *Ctrl+N (Alt+O for OS X)* such as a table, view, procedure, etc. Just type the name or an abbreviation of the object you need. *Ctrl+Alt+Shift+N (Alt+Cmd+O for OSX)* includes more objects in the search scope like column, indexes etc.

[image]