# Filtering the list of tables in JetBrains Datagrip

Tags: datagrip

I have recently started using JetBrains DataGrip as a replacement for HeidiSQL.

My issue relates to the list of tables in the Database Explorer.  We have a large database (700+ tables) and scrolling to find the table I'm looking for is rather cumbersome.  For a table with a nice, long, specific name I can just start typing and get the highlighting on the table names, which usually takes me right where I need to go:

[image: Screenshot of the Database Explorer showing the highlighting]

But if I'm trying to get to the table `user` and we have lots of other tables with "user" in the name in various positions, the highlighting tool only takes me to the first table with "user" in the name, which is not the actual "user" table (and because we have tables with names like `billingUsers`, it doesn't scroll to anywhere near the actual `user` table that I'm looking for).

What other methods should I be using when I want to find a particular table in DataGrip?  In HeidiSQL, there was the "filter tables" box which would *filter* the list of tables based on the search term, which got me much closer to my intended destination much more quickly.  Does DataGrip have any sort of "quick filter" like this?  Or is there some other tool or prompt I should use to go directly to this table instead?

During the writing of this question I came across the "double Shift" shortcut, which is helpful and closer to what I'm looking for -- though in my case I have several of our development environments configured in DataGrip, and it lists the table in every environment - whereas in the Database Explorer, I usually only have one environment expanded at a time (and only want to see results from that database, not the others).

StackOverflow suggested [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45265061/jetbrains-datagrip-search-utility) to me, which has the same issue as the double-Shift shortcut -- it shows results from all databases, not just the one I'm working in.

Comment: Also, regarding searching in current data source:

It is possible if you use 'Database' tab (Cmd/O or Ctrl+N shortcut), because you can narrow the search down to the 'context data source'. See pic: https://imgur.com/iKvQj7W

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPD**: the filter in teh database tree is implemented:

[image]

---

I am from the DataGrip team. We are currently working on that and expect the filtering functionality in 2022.3. Anyway, now there are several workarounds (and Shift+Shift is one of them). See them here:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-3017/Show-only-filtered-items-when-typing-in-the-database-explorer

Comment: I need this to filter out indexes (a33. d34, i33 and so on) so it would be great if a filter (RegEx) could be applied to the views in the tree.

Comment: Sorry, it is not clear